# Codons Translation

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I have been trying to do this little project where I make a program which the user will input three ammio acids like "ATC" and in return the program will tell it, its protein, but what I have written seems to not do what I want it

```
Codon = print(input(str("Please enter your codon: ")))
if Codon == ("ATT", "ATC", "ATA"):
    print("Isoleucine")
elif Codon == ("CTT", "CTC", "CTA", "CTG", "TTA", "TTG"):
    print("Leucine")
elif Codon == ("GTT", "GTC", "GTA", "GTG"):
    print("Valine")
elif Codon == ("TTT", "TTC"):
    print("Phenylalanine")
elif Codon == "ATG":
    print("Methionine")
elif Codon == ("TGT", "TGC"):
    print("Cysteine")
elif Codon == ("GCT", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG"):
    print("Alanine")
elif Codon == ("GGT", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"):
    print("CodonGlycine")
elif Codon == ("CCT", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"):
    print("Proline")
elif Codon == ("ACT", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG"):
    print("Threonine")
elif Codon == ("TCT", "TCC", "TCA", "TCG", "AGT", "AGC"):
    print("Serine")
elif Codon == ("TAT", "TAC"):
    print("Tyrosine")
elif Codon == "TGG":
    print("Tryptophan")
elif Codon == ("CAA", "CAG"):
    print("Glutamine")
elif Codon == ("AAT", "AAC"):
    print("Asparagine")
elif Codon == ("CAT", "CAC"):
    print("Histidine")
elif Codon == ("GAA", "GAG"):
    print("Glutamic_Acid")
elif Codon == ("GAT", "GAC"):
    print("Aspartic_Acid")
elif Codon == ("AAA", "AAG"):
    print("Lysine")
elif Codon == ("CGT", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AGA", "AGG"):
    print("Arginine")
elif Codon == ("TAA", "TAG", "TGA"):
    print("Stop_Codons")
else:print("Something Went Wrong")
```

This output:

> `Please enter your codon: TGA
>   TGA
>   Something Went Wrong`

What I want it to output:

```
Stop_Codon
```

any suggestions/help would be really appreciated 
Also I need to make it so it can accept lowercase letters as well, at this stage if one was to enter a lower case codon, it would just not work as intended!

Comment: You should use `in` instead of `==`...

Comment: I guess you have to write `Codon in (...): ` instead of `==`

Comment: Also, `Codon = print(input(str("Please enter your codon: ")))` should just be `Codon = input("Please enter your codon: ")`

Comment: Please don't edit in extra, unrelated questions at the end once it has already been answered. You just need `Codon = input("Please enter your codon: ").upper()` but in future, research that point separately and if you can't find the answer, raise as another question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Use a dictionary. You save each Codon as a key with it's corresponding Protein name. Then when the user inputs the codon you just pick the value from the dictionary. It's way cleaner than using conditionals with `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 1):

If you write:

```
if Codon == ("ATT", "ATC", "ATA"):
```

Python will check if the `Codon` (a `str`ing) is **equal** to the tuple containing these three elements. Now since the type is not equal, it will not match the test. What you need is `in` to check if the `Codon` (for instance `"ATC"`) is **in the tuple**. So:

```
if Codon in ("ATT", "ATC", "ATA"):
#        ^ use in
```

Furthermore you write:

```
Codon = print(input(str("Please enter your codon: ")))
#       ^ print??
```

Now `print` prints the input, and **returns `None`**. So you should rewrite it to:

```
Codon = input(str("Please enter your codon: ")).strip()
#                                               ^ strip the new line
```

Nevertheless you better use a `dict`ionary for that.

Comment: It was staring me right in the face, but I couldn't figure it out, thanks alot of the help!